# Jenkins Jira Integration

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have configured Jenkin Job to run my cucumber project .
Now, I want to automatically upload the test result/report of a test suite I run in Jenkins against the Test suite I have in JIRA.

Kindly let me know the answer

Comment: Hi Niharika, welcome to S.O!! Do you need a simple upload document to your issue in jira? Do you have an screenshot to your Test Suite in Jira?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking time to show interest in my query.
I have to automatically  add Cucumber test reports after the build is run on Jenkins  into Jira . With all screenahots

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin below for jenkins should help you with your task

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JiraTestResultReporter-plugin